# How to close a specific program from the system tray Using AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a specific program that is running in the system tray icon ("ahk_exe QTranslate.exe"), I want it to be closed automatically from the system tray icon if it is running whenever I open another specific program ("ahk_exe phpstorm64.exe").

I've tried this, But this closes only the window of ("QTranslate") If it is exist, But The program still running in the system tray :

```
loop{
    WinWaitActive, ahk_exe phpstorm64.exe
    if WinExist("ahk_exe QTranslate.exe")
    {
        WinKill, ahk_exe QTranslate.exe
    }
}
```

- Is there any script to close the specified program from the system?
- Note I use : AutoHotkey V1.1.36.02
- Please help! I appreciate your time and effort. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just tell ahk to unconditionally kill the process using `Process, Close, QTranslate.exe` and then `WinWaitNotActive, ahk_exe phpstorm64.exe` to hold the loop until you deactivate and reactivate phpstorm. No `if` needed and you can rerun QTranslate whenever you like. 3 lines in your loop and no conditionals needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Persistent

SetTimer, close_QTranslate, 500
    return
    
    close_QTranslate:
If !ProcessExist("phpstorm64.exe") ; "!" means "NOT" in this case
    return ; do nothing
; otherwise:
If ProcessExist("QTranslate.exe")
    Process, Close, QTranslate.exe
return

ProcessExist(name){
    Process, Exist, %name%
        return Errorlevel
}
```